# Can I have a front-end on Airflow?

Tags: web-applications, airflow, airflow-scheduler, data-processing

I want to expose a front-end user interface to accept some input parameters from the users for a data pipeline in the backend and then display the output to the user again on the front-end user interface. I can have the data pipeline as an Airflow DAG which is run on-demand whenever the user submits the input params. Essentially, I want to have Airflow as the backend for a web-app. Can I have a continuously running DAG that serves web-page to the user and whenever they submit input params, the data pipeline in executed and the result is displayed?

I found a close example - https://towardsdatascience.com/10-minutes-to-building-a-machine-learning-pipeline-with-apache-airflow-53cd09268977 but I'm not sure if it serves a web-page continuously or only when the DAG is run and then stops when DAG completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common solution in projects that I have worked on, have involved surfacing [Flask App or Flask App Builder](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) objects through the [plugins folder in your setup](https://flynn.gg/blog/airflow-flask-plugins/#:%7E:text=The%20Airflow%20web%20application%20is,views%2C%20blueprints%2C%20and%20templates.).

The second link should take you through a good example.

From here you can have you Flask app essentially call Airflow models or interact with the backend database by using the Session concept from [airflow/utils/db.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/db.py).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

One way is you could expose APIs for interacting with Airflow by writing custom plugin as mentioned in the previous answer.

Another way I could think of is leveraging the Airflow command-line interface. Basically making your UI execute Airflow commands remotely somwhow. Luckily there is a plugin that already does this. [Airflow REST API Plugin](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin) exposes the Airflow command-line interface as REST APIs. I have not tried it personally. But explored it while we were in need of an API for some operation. From the documentation it appears to be stable and well maintained.

Comment: Nice. Seems helpful. Does it also support passing custom arguments or parameters to the DAG? That's the main purpose of the UI - to be able to pass custom config for running the DAG.

Comment: I have not tried it. However, from the docs it appears to have what you are asking [https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin#trigger_dag](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin#trigger_dag)